# Getting .user.ini to work

Tags: php, file-upload

I'm trying to use upload_max_filesize and with my research I found out that I can't use ini_set(). I also saw that I could create a file called .user.ini, I tried that and it didn't seem to work, I don't know if maybe I'm doing something wrong.

What I do is I create the file in my root directory and I add

```
upload_max_filesize = "10M"
```

to the file and save it. But when I check my phpinfo(), I still have upload_max_filesize = "2M"

I'm trying not to touch my .htaccess and I don't have access to the php.ini file.